# How to return a column when checking for duplicates?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I need to find all records that the FIRSTNAME is a Duplicate and the LASTNAME is a duplicate

So my data kinda looks like this:

```
FirstName    LastName    CustomerFileLocation    
   Joe        Smith         c:\file1     
   Joe        Jones         c:\File2     
   Joe        Smith         c:\File3     
   Harry      Smith         c:\File4
```

I want the query to return

```
Joe      Smith      c:\file1
Joe      Smith      c:\File3
```

I wrote this to select them, but it if I add the CustomerFileLocation to the GROUP BY expression it returns nothing.

```
SELECT        FirstName, LastName, COUNT(1) AS CNT, CustomerFileLocation
FROM            tblCustomerList
WHERE        (Skip = 0)
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
HAVING        (COUNT(1) > 1)
```

Comment: Why is the file location stored as `ntext`? What is the longest value it actually contains?

Comment: I changed the data type from vtext to nvarchar to eliminate that from the equation of issues I am dealing with.  So now I just need to find all records which both FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME match and return the FileName

Comment: What is the primary key of the table? Which system are you actually using? MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server. You have tagged both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a subquery to return the table containing any records that have a count greater than 1 then inner join your table back on that subquery.

Haven't tried it but it would look something like this.

```
SELECT tblCustomerList.FirstName, tblCustomerList.LastName, tblCustomerList.CustomerFileLocation From (SELECT FirstName, LastName, COUNT(1) AS CNT, CustomerFileLocation
FROM tblCustomerList
WHERE
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
HAVING (COUNT(1) > 1))) as countTable inner join tblCustomerList 
on countTable.lastname = tblCustomerList.lastname and countTable.firstname = tblCustomerList.firstname and tblCustomerList.Skip = 0
```

Comment: This is what I spent all day and solved about 5 minutes BEFORE your extremely helpful post!

Comment: I have a revision.  Maybe you can help me with.   Psuedo:  Select All Records where FirstName & LastName Match but City is different and return CustomerFileLocation

Comment: SELECT tblCustomerList.FirstName, tblCustomerList.LastName, tblCustomerList.CustomerFileLocation From (SELECT FirstName, LastName, city, COUNT(1) AS CNT, CustomerFileLocation
FROM tblCustomerList
WHERE
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, city
HAVING (COUNT(1) > 1))) as countTable inner join tblCustomerList 
on countTable.lastname = tblCustomerList.lastname and countTable.firstname = tblCustomerList.firstname and countTable.city = tblCustomerList.city and tblCustomerList.Skip = 0

Comment: Sorry for the poor format. Sent from my iphone. You are just adding the city column to the sub query and group by statement then on the inner join make sure you're adding the additional links on city as well

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) as fullname, 
       cast(CustomerFileLocation as nvarchar) as location 
FROM tblCustomerList WHERE (Skip = 0) GROUP BY  (FirstName + ' ' + LastName), 
cast(customerFileLication as nvarchar) having count(1)>1
```

I haven't tested or tuned it for performance but something along this line must work.

Comment: SQL Scripting is not a strong point for me (Or I wouldn't have posted the question here).  The script you gave me doesn't work.  
I changed the data type from vtext to nvarchar to eliminate that from the equation of issues I am dealing with.  So now I just need to find all records which both FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME match and return the FileName